# php shows one hour early

Tags: php, time, timezone

php settings in `php.ini`:

```
date.timezone = Asia/Jerusalem.
```

My Linux server (Ubuntu) shows the **correct time:** `Wed Oct 1 15:35:39 IDT 2014`

But when I `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` I get `2014-10-01 14:35:39` (One hour earlier).

I also tried to `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');` but the results are the same

Why is the result off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Israel has undergone several changes to daylight saving time in the last few years.  This year, DST is supposed to be in effect until October 26th.  The last time the DST end date fell before October 1st was September 23, 2012.  [Reference here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/israel/jerusalem?syear=2010&eyear=2015).

When Israel announced the changes for 2013 forward, they were released in the standard [IANA time zone database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones) in version 2013d.  I actually [answered a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18340343/634824) back then, regarding how Java handles this change.

For PHP, the IANA database is implemented via the [timezonedb PECL package](http://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).  You can install this package manually to update to the latest version of the timezone data.

PHP also comes with a copy of timezonedb internally, which is supposed to be the most recent version available at the time that the PHP version is released.  So simply upgrading PHP to the latest version should also solve the problem.

If you want to see what version of timezonedb you currently have (whether built-in, or updated) - you can call `timezone_version_get()`, [as documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-version-get.php).   It needs to be at least 2013.4 to have this particular change.  The current release is 2014.7.

Comment: There goes hours of frustration. my version is 2011.8... One thing, how am I going about installing this PECL, my server doesn't even have PECL. Should I install PECL just for that? Is this a normal thing to do?

Comment: You can read through [the PECL installation docs](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php).  Or you might want to just upgrade to the [latest release of PHP](http://php.net/downloads.php).

Comment: And yes, it's quite normal to use PECL for many reasons.  It's also quite normal (and recommended) to stay on top of timezonedb updates.  Especially if your application has functionality dependent on accurate interpretation of the world's time zones.

Comment: If you're running Linux, you may find [this](http://www.amitnepal.com/installing-php-time-zone-database/) or [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/correct-php-timezone/) useful.

Comment: You are an angel! Thank you!!

Comment: May I only ask why then did MySQL remain ok throughout the process? It showed the correct time just like my server did... Your answer solved my problem, but it intrigues me why it worked for MySQL?

Comment: MySQL has a [different update process](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-upgrades.html).  Depending on what you're doing, you may have also been impacted by the timezone data from your OS.  Ubuntu uses the [tzdata package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata), and it's likely to have been updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You solve it by setting the timezone explicitly in your PHP scripts. You can do this with [date_default_timezone_set():](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');
```

Here is the list of PHP supported timezones.

You may also want to try a test script calling `date_default_timezone_get()` to see what it's actually set to to verify that this is in fact the problem.

[List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Still getting it off. I replied to @tehnuty about that

Answer (score 0):

Set and check your time zone in php.

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // here set the time zone

  $script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

  if (strcmp($script_tz, ini_get('date.timezone'))){
     echo 'Script timezone differs from ini-set timezone.';
  } else {
     echo 'Script timezone and ini-set timezone match.';
  }
?>
```

Comment: My timezone is set properly, I do however get the time off by one hour

Comment: Your script replied to me with a timeone match

Answer (score 0):

The Asia/Jerusalem timezone has daylight savings time currently in effect; it may be that php isn't handling this. The function call `date('I')` will return `1` if your php is currently running DST, `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Change the php timezone:

1) Open the php.ini file - `vim /etc/php.ini`

2) Change the default timezone settings by adding/modifying this line:

`date.timezone = Asia/Jerusalem` - remove the `;` at the first of line (if exists)!

3) Save the php.ini file.

4) Restart the Apache server - `systemctl restart httpd.service`. 
The timezone settings should now be modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

echo date_default_timezone_get()."
";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."
";
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem')."
"; // Change to what you want
echo date_default_timezone_get()."
";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

I would not recommend changing it in PHP.ini as you may have visitors from any place in the world. Using JavaScript is the best way to create the date on the front end.