# Show message before and after certain time

Tags: php, date, time

Currently i am working on a webshop which sends it's orders placed before 17:00 the same day. On the succes or thank-you page i would like to place a message if it's before 17:00, after 17:00 and in the weekends. So three messages.

I'm trying this with PHP now:

```
<?php
            //Show message
            $before_17 = "Order received before 17:00, will ship today.";
            $after_17="Order placed after 17:00, will ship tomorrow.";
            $weekend = "It's weekend, order will be shipped on Monday.";

            //Time & Day
            $current_time = date(H);
            $current_day = date(D);

            //Saturday
            if ($current_day == Sat){
            echo $weekend;
            }

            //Sunday
            elseif ($current_day == Sun){
            echo $weekend;
            }

            //Weekdays > 17
            elseif ($current_time > 17){
            echo $after_17;
            }

            //Weekdays < 17
            elseif($current_time < 17){
            echo $before_17;
            }

            else{
            echo 'Niks';
            }
        ?>
```

I was hoping this should do the trick, but the page still shows the $before_17 after 17:00. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the server is set for the time zone and DST you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT;
I just noticed another issue. You should use `if ($current_time >= 17)` (not just greater than) otherwise it will not take effect until the hour is 18.

Also you should use quotes in `date()`! Try `date('H')` & `date('D')` instead of `date(H)` and `date(D)`. And quotes in the day comparisons `if ($current_day === 'Sun')`.

Failing that, you should `echo date('H');` To make sure the time on the server is set correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Thats why my after_17 action is only triggered at the right time if i enter 16 as hour, i guess.

Comment: Can i also do this with hours and minutes, so i trigger the after_17 if it's 17.01 and the before_17 untill 17.00 or something?

Comment: Yes, I think you should be able to do `$current_time = date('H.i');` then `if($current_time >= 17.01)` as the test. But I think just using the hour is all you need if you use `>=` to stipulate greater than or equal to 17.

Answer (score 0):

1 - use quotes in date(). like `date('D')`

2- use quotes in comparing strings in if. like `if($current_day=='Sun')`

Answer (score 0):

This could be related to time zone issue

I encountered the same bug ($current_time was 16 even though it should have been 17)

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141506/php-shows-one-hour-early) for more info

Comment: So i have added the set_timeline code to my php. It's working better now, but in the after_17 i have to enter "16" as time to make it work correctly. Is this how it works?

Comment: Do you mean `setTimezone()`? You also need to actually check the server time with `echo date('H:i');` to check it. It could be the time on the server is incorrect in which case `setTimezone()` will also be incorrect.