# PHP returns wrong time even when using correct timezone

Tags: php, timezone

I have a weird issue with php time that is different than actual system time, even though both have same timezone.

Timezone is set to `Asia/Jerusalem`, both in system clock, and on `php.ini`.

I checked the timezone in the command line, and it is correct.

```
> php -r "echo date_default_timezone_get();"
Asia/Jerusalem
```

But time has an offset of 1 hour to system clock (and to actual time in Israel).

```
> php -r "echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');"
2022-09-05 11:56:39
```

```
> php -i | Select-String -Pattern "timezone"
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 2021.5
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => Asia/Jerusalem
date.timezone => Asia/Jerusalem => Asia/Jerusalem
```

[image]

What can be the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php shows one hour early](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141506/php-shows-one-hour-early)

Comment: My timezone database version is 2021, so I am not sure if it helps.

Comment: There is a newer version of the timezone database released August 11. You may want to update to that one and test to see if the DST changes have been added.

Comment: Each version of PHP is released with the latest TZDB available.  So the easiest way is to install the latest version of PHP.  That would explain the hour difference, but not the minutes.  I presume that's just from delay in taking the screenshot?

Comment: yes, the only issue is the 1 hour difference, the minutes are ok. The php version was 7.3. I want to avoid installing php version 8 if I can. I will try to install latest version of TZDB and see if it makes a difference

Comment: When the difference is one hour, the obvious thing to check is Daylight Saving.

Comment: @justadev - You can update to the latest v7 if you prefer (7.4.30 presently).  If you want to install the time zone data yourself, it's via the [timezonedb PECL package](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb).  However - others have reported this is difficult on Windows.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564478/how-to-update-timezonedb-in-php-updating-timezones-info